# Why do some traditions recite the Lord's Prayer word for word?

Tags: prayer, lords-prayer

Why do some traditions recite the Lord's Prayer word for word?

I know a lot of Christians that do this, but I am having trouble understanding why. Is the Lord's prayer recited by anyone anywhere else in the Bible other than when Jesus first says it to the disciples?

Comment: this is related and addresses the first part of your question http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7098/432             As for the second part there is no other repetition of the Lord's prayer as far as I am aware in the NT.

Comment: Welcome to _Christianity--StackExchange_!  I agree with @ryanOptini--we've had a virtually identical question.  Point #2 is a different question, but it's pretty easy to answer with a quick [search](http://www.esvbible.org/search/hallowed/) or a check of a study Bible's cross-references.  But you could probably edit the question to get at what you seem to be really asking, which is why some traditions recite the prayer word for word.

Comment: thanks for the comments. i didn't see that other topic which has good information on this topic.

Comment: yeah, that is perhaps what i'm really wondering, jon -i updated the question

Answer (score 5):

There are two main reasons we recite the Lord's Prayer in worship:

- It is a model prayer that Jesus gave us to teach us how to pray. We recite it to remind ourselves what genuine prayer looks like.
- We pray it as a group to unify the congregation. When we recite the Lord's Prayer, we are all speaking to God with one voice.

Answer (score 3):

> 2) Is the Lord's prayer recited by anyone anywhere else in the Bible other than when Jesus first says it to the disciples?

There are similarities between the Lord's Prayer and others prayers recited in those days as the [Kaddish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaddish).  So it could be said that Jesus used a common pattern to make up His prayer based in what they know: Jewish traditions. We don't have references to say that anyone anywhere else recited it.